# how to catch input exception for a scanner

Tags: java

I need to scan a number and then sort it in a list. How can i make the program ignore if a user types in letters instead of a number.
it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException.
```

code:

```
public static void InsertionSort() {

        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int x=-2;
        while(x!=-1)
        {   
            System.out.println("type a number to place in a sorted list");
            x=scan.nextInt();
        }
        scan.close();
    }
```

Comment: Have you learned about try-catch?

Comment: `nextInt()` expects an int, so you can try to use `next()` instead, that returns a String. Then check if the String is an int before continuing. Otherwise ignore it or throw an exception

Comment: See "example 1" in the given link. It gives you the tools you need.

Comment: Use scan.hasNextInt() and check if true